# How to log all Bash commands by all users on a server?

Tags: bash, logging

Our small company runs an Ubuntu Server 11.10, to which a couple of people have SSH access. The actual terminals are sometimes used, too. How can we locally log all Bash commands run, along with user and time stamp?

We can assume that no-one is nefarious and actively trying to avoid the logging, but we'd still prefer the users not to have direct write-access to their log files. Simultaneous sessions must be handled correctly.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For BASH shells, edit the system-wide BASH runtime config file:

```
sudo -e /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Append to the end of that file:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'
```

Set up logging for "local6" with a new file:

```
sudo -e /etc/rsyslog.d/bash.conf
```

And the contents...

```
local6.*    /var/log/commands.log
```

Restart rsyslog:

```
sudo service rsyslog restart
```

Log out. Log in. Voila!

But I forgot about log rotation:

```
sudo -e /etc/logrotate.d/rsyslog
```

There is a list of log files to rotate the same way...

```
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
[...]
/var/log/message
```

So add the new bash-commands log file in that list:

```
/var/log/commands.log
```

Save.

Comment: Forgot about log rotation which I added to the answer.

Comment: This way works, but I could invent a method around it (with csh, .bash_logout perhaps). I would go with Sabacon's acct solution. These were excellent reads: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6144 and http://beginlinux.com/blog/2010/01/monitoring-user-activity-with-psacct-or-acct/

Comment: I believe this can be easily deactivated by the user by simply resetting or unsetting `PROMPT_COMMAND` or exec-ing to a non-bash shell.

Comment: Is there anything special about `local6`? What does it refer to?

Comment: @Benubird it looks like there's a few preset facility levels, 8 of them being local0-local7: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog . 0 means emergency, 7 means debug, and 6 is just shy of 7, "normal operational messages."

Comment: what does rotate mean!?

Comment: I am unable to log commands running in scripts, using this method.

Comment: @yukashima because logs can become big files if not deleted, rotating means to rotate the log files and delet the older ones to keep logs smaller...

Answer (score 5):

A process accounting system may be helpful in this regard, particularly the [acct](http://packages.ubuntu.com/acct) package that provides the lastcomm and ac commands.

The ac commands prints out statistics about users' connection time, in hours. This is the amount of time that the user has been connected to the system, either remotely via SSH or a serial terminal, or while on the console.

The lastcomm command displays information about the previously executed commands. The most recent entries are given at the top of the list. Also displayed is the total amount of CPU time that each process used.

An old tutorial that may be helpful is here:

http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6144?page=0,1

Other accounting commands like last and so on can be found in this tutorial:

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/system-accounting-in-linux/1053377

Comment: lastcomm is pretty pointless as a command logger.  It only records the executable that was run.  No arguments, switches or paths are logged.

Comment: lastcomm logs a lot of garbage. I see endless lists of "df, tail, head, sleep, who" commands that nobody run.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [snoopy](https://github.com/a2o/snoopy).

Snoopy logger may suit your purpose well. It is not intended to be unavoidable logging solution, but rather a helpful tool for diligent admins who prefer to keep track of their own actions.

Disclosure: I am snoopy maintainer.

Comment: Please provide instructions on installing and using it in the answer.

Comment: Detailed installation instructions are available on the snoopy github page, which is the main snoopy resource right now: https://github.com/a2o/snoopy. I am agains providing installation instructions in other places as primary location is maintained by design and others are not. BTW Readme was just updated to be more structured.

Comment: Maybe so. But without even a summary of the steps needed to use this, this is a link-only answer and likely to be deleted.

Comment: I visited your link and I assume that the installation instructions for Ubuntu would be `sudo make install` and `sudo reboot` instead of `make install` and `reboot`, but what about the `make enable` command? Would that command need to be prefixed by `sudo` in Ubuntu?

Comment: Well, I provided a pointer to an alternative and viable solution. If that is not what this site is all about, then by all means it should get deleted, together with my account.

Comment: @karel : Yes, make enable writes to /etc/ld.so.preload. Root privileges are essential.

Comment: Thank you. The installation procedure is clear to me now. For any others who may have any general questions about the installation procedure, please read [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file/1030#1030).

Comment: @karel Do feel free to contribute detailed Ubuntu-specific installation instructions in contrib/ubuntu/README... I will gladly merge it and make a pointer to in in main README.md.

Comment: @BostjanSkufca no need to be offended. It's just a Stack Exchange thing to have at least reasonably self-contained answers. If you're so strongly opposed to adding steps, that's your wish. My downvote remains. Someone will probably upvote it.

Comment: Not offended. I understand now (about self-contained answers).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try installing acct. Acct keeps a detailed audit trail of what’s being done on your Linux systems.

```
sudo apt-get install acct
```

Answer (score 0):

To take care of multiple sessions not over-writing the history file, you will have to put "shopt -s histappend" in a Bash startup file. See, also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393574/logging-of-commands-executed-in-bash) on the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this (the solutions above will not work 100% with bash 4.3):

```
export HISTTIMEFORMAT="%Y-%m-%d %T "
export PROMPT_COMMAND='trap "" 1 2 15; history -a >(tee -a ~/.bash_history | while read line; do if [[ $line =~ ^#[0-9]*$ ]]; then continue; fi; logger -p user.info -t "bash[$$]" "($USER) $line"; done); trap 1 2 15;'
```

this does the logging AND it prevents logging of timestamps that are used for the bash history file. the trap is needed, since bash will send the signals to the "subjob" after pressing strg+c multiple times (tested with bash 4.3). this will force the logout of the current user (e.g. logged in with sudo)